# Adding columns to a csv file, based on data from multiple files, using Python?

Tags: python

I'm getting raw data then reordering the columns, adding data based on data from multiple files, adding some hardcoded data, then saving to an "output.csv" file.

For example...

File1.csv: (Retrieved Data)
person, date_time, site, status

```
Person1,01/13/16 10:38,SiteA,I
Person1,01/20/16 12:53,SiteC,O
Person2,01/21/16 14:45,SiteB,O
Person3,01/17/16 12:17,SiteA,I
Person3,01/25/16 10:15,SiteB,L
```

File2.csv: (Fixed Data_1)
site,code

```
SiteA,101
SiteB,102
SiteC,103
```

File3.csv: (Fixed Data_2)
period_start_time,period_end_time,period

```
00:00,07:59,0
08:00,09:00,1
09:01,10:00,2
10:01,11:00,3
11:01,12:00,4
12:01,13:00,5
13:01,14:00,6
14:01,15:00,7
15:01,23:59,X
```

File1 has raw data.
The last column has a "I", "O" and a "L".
The "I" stands for IN.
The "O" stands for OUT.
The "L" stands for LATE.

This example has three students that have gone in or out of sites A, B or C.
Note, if they are "L" or LATE they are still going IN.

File2 has "site codes".

File3 has a first column stating the period_start_time and the second is the period_end_time.
The third column is the period.

I need to create a output.csv file:
WHERE,WHOM,PERIOD,DATE,TIME_IN,TIME_OUT,USERNAME

WHERE = needs to be the corresponding site code from File2.
WHOM = is the person.
PERIOD = if the time is 10:38, then the period is "3", given by File3.
DATE = show time as 'mm/dd/yy'.
TIME_IN = show time as 'HH:MM' if the status is "I" or "L", leave blank if it doesn't.
TIME_OUT = show time as 'HH:MM' if the status is "O", leave blank if it doesn't.
USERNAME = is hardcoded "Username".

The output.csv file should read like this, given the example data above.

output.csv: (Reformatted Data)

```
101,Person1,3,01/13/16,10:38,,Username
103,Person1,5,01/20/16,,12:53,Username
102,Person2,7,01/21/16,,14:45,Username
101,Person3,5,01/17/16,12:17,,Username
102,Person3,3,01/25/16,10:15,,Username
```

Note the corresponding code in the first column.
Also note the PERIOD, and the blanks for TIME_IN and TIME_OUT columns.

---

Finally got it.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import csv

class TimePeriod:
    def __init__(self, starttime, endtime, periodname):
        self.starttime = starttime
        self.endtime = endtime
        self.periodname = periodname

def get_time_list(time_file):
    timelist = list()
    with open(time_file) as inputs:
        for line in inputs:
            starttime, endtime, periodname = line.strip().split(",")
            timelist.append(TimePeriod(starttime, endtime, periodname))                
    return timelist

def get_site_code_dict(site_code_file):
    mydict = dict()
    with open(site_code_file) as inputs:
        for line in inputs:
            site,code = line.strip().split(",")
            mydict[site] = code
    return mydict

def process_raw(raw_file, site_code_dict):
    with open(raw_file) as inputs, open('ouput.csv', 'w') as outlist:
        for line in inputs:
            person, date_time, site, status = line.strip().split(",")
            time_object = dt.strptime(date_time, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
            date = time_object.strftime('%m/%d/%y')
            time = time_object.strftime('%H:%M')
            filteredlist = filter(lambda x: time >= x.starttime and time <= x.endtime, time_list)
            outlist.write(site_code_dict[site]+',')
            outlist.write(person+',')
            outlist.write(date+',')
            outlist.write(filteredlist[0].periodname+',')
            if status == "I" or status == "L":
                outlist.write(time+',')
            else:
                outlist.write(""+',')
            if status == "O":
                outlist.write(time+',')
            else:
                outlist.write(""+',')
            outlist.write("Username"+'\n')
    outlist.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    site_code_dict = get_site_code_dict("file2.csv")
    time_list = get_time_list("file3.csv")
    process_raw("file1.csv", site_code_dict)
```

Output data from the csv file:

```
101,Person1,01/13/16,3,10:38,,Username
103,Person1,01/20/16,5,,12:53,Username
102,Person2,01/21/16,7,,14:45,Username
101,Person3,01/17/16,5,12:17,,Username
102,Person3,01/25/16,3,10:15,,Username
```

With the above code, I've got the columns in order.
The 1st column has the correct code.
The DATE column has the just the date in 'mm/dd/yy' format.
The TIME_IN column has only military time, if the record is "I" or "L".
And the TIME_OUT column has military time time, if it is "O".
I have the period done, by using a "class" TimePeriod.

Thanks for the help, as I am very much a novice.

Comment: First load file 2 create a mapping of site to code. Then as you parse file 1 maintain a list of persons who are in, including all their other data and when you see their out line write to the file and remove them from the list. You may have to do a sweep at the end of the day for any in entries that don't have a matching out.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_site_code_dict(site_code_file):
    mydict = dict()
    with open(site_code_file) as inputs:
        for line in inputs:
            site,code = line.strip().split(",")
            mydict[site] = code
    return mydict


def process_raw(raw_file, site_code_dict):
    with open(raw_file) as inputs:
        for line in inputs:
            person, date_time, site, status = line.strip().split(",")
            outlist = list()
            outlist.append(site_code_dict[site])
            outlist.append(person)
            outlist.append(date_time)
            outlist.append(status)
            print ",".join(outlist)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    site_code_dict = get_site_code_dict("file2")
    process_raw("file1", site_code_dict)
```

Output:

```
101,Person1,01/13/16 10:38,I
103,Person1,01/20/16 12:53,O
102,Person2,01/21/16 14:45,O
```

You can create key-value pair as `get_site_code_dict` to bind the site name and code number, and then use it to process your raw data.

Comment: Thanks, this works and looks nice.  You answered the basic question, but the output data is not quite done.  The status column is not needed in the output data. I did edit the question by adding some hardcoded text for the last column. But the 3rd and 4th column are populated by the status. If "I" or "L" populate time in the 3rd, and if "O" populate the 4th.

Comment: glad to know it helped

Comment: instead of print, how to save the list to a .csv file? I've been trying but I just get a file with the last line in there.